# Possible lossy from int to char; Occurs when reading in from a text file

Tags: java, algorithm, char, int

I am trying to implement the Shunting Algorithm, but after I read in a character, I will need to determine if it is an operand or an operator. The input file has multiple lines of infix expressions that I will convert to postfix expressions and evaluate. So I need to read each character of each line, evaluate, and then proceed to the next line. The error that I get is:

> "error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to char"

So here is a portion of what I have so far:

```
 BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));

        char token;
        char popOp;
        int popInt1;
        int popInt2;
        int result;
        String line;
        char temp = 'a';

        // While the input file still has a line with characters
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
        {
            // Create an operator and operand stack                         
            operatorStack opStack = new operatorStack();
            opStack.push(';');
            operandStack intStack = new operandStack();

            token = input.read(); // Get the first token

            if(Character.isDigit(token))
            {
                System.out.print(token);
                intStack.push(token);
            }
            else if(token == ')')
            {........
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could I do something like... `if input.read().hasNextInt()` for the integer/operand and then just do else for the operator?

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on? Is it an Exception or a compilation failure?

Comment: It is the line that says `token = input.read();` It is a compilation failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues with your code:

1. `BufferedReader.read()` returns `-1` if you've reached the end of the stream. You're not handling this.
2. You are already reading the text line into `line` so when you call `input.read()` it reads the first char of the next line! You could either use  `line.charAt(0)` or just use `input.read()`.

This might fix your problem:

```
   // While there are characters to consume.
    for(int ch; (ch = input.read()) != -1;)
    {
        // Create an operator and operand stack                         
        operatorStack opStack = new operatorStack();
        opStack.push(';');
        operandStack intStack = new operandStack();

        token = (char)ch; // Get the token

        if(token == '\r' || token == '\n')  // handling line ends.
             continue;

        if(Character.isDigit(token))
        {
            System.out.print(token);
            intStack.push(token);
        }
        else if(token == ')')
        {........
```

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader` returns an `int`. The program above is trying to store that result to a `char` variable. Typecasting it to `char` should fix it:

```
token = (char)input.read();
```